# Sending a sub-segment of an ArrayBuffer over a WebSocket without copying

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am populating an `ArrayBuffer` with data to be sent over a `WebSocket`.

The data has variable size, so while serialising I dynamically extend the `ArrayBuffer` as needed.

However when the serialisation process completes I often have unused space at the end of the buffer that I do not want to send.

It's possible to copy the required section out to a new `ArrayBuffer`, but this is wasteful in terms of memory and CPU.

Is it possible to sent a sub-portion of an `ArrayBuffer` over a `WebSocket` without copying? If not, is there another way I can go about this that will avoid the performance hit of copying?

---

Edit with some clarification.

The core problem is that [`WebSocket.send`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#send()) only accepts `DOMString`, `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob`. These all seem to require a complete buffer, not a view onto a buffer.

I do not know how big the buffer will be when I start serialisation, so it starts at 64 bytes and doubles on each overflow. That's already *some* copying, but I can tune the initial size so that overflows are the exception. What I want to avoid is having to copy the serialised data out of the over-sized buffer.

In psuedo-JS:

```
function serialiseAndSend(webSocket, message) {

    // Allocate a buffer (assume it's large enough)
    const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(64);

    // Serialise into that buffer, and obtain the number of bytes written (<= 64)
    const bytesWritten = serialise(buffer, message);

    // The first 'bytesWritten' bytes of 'buffer' contain my message, the rest is zeroed.
    //
    // I want to send that sub-portion without allocating another buffer.

    // This function would be great (buffer, start, count) but doesn't exist
    webSocket.send(buffer, 0, bytesWritten); 

    // Instead I think I have to allocate and send a copy
    const copy = buffer.slice(0, bytesWritten);
    webSocket.send(copy);
}
```

This pattern is common on other platforms/languages, and seems like an oversight in the WebSocket API. However I know it was designed experienced developers and am hoping there's a means to do what I'm after that I haven't encountered yet.

Comment: _"The core problem is that `WebSocket.send` only accepts `DOMString`, `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob`"_ That is not accurate. `.send()` also accepts a `TypedArray` as argument. _"This function would be great (buffer, start, count) but doesn't exist"_ That options does exist using `.subarray()`, as demonstrated at Answer `webSocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer"; let ab = new Uint8Array(buffer); let segment = ab.subarray(0, bytesWritten); webSocket.send(segment)`. Note,  `.slice()` is not the same as `.subarray()`

Comment: _"The core problem is that `WebSocket.send` only accepts `DOMString`, `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob`"_ Note, MDN is not the specification, the actual [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#network) also includes [`ArrayBufferView`](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#common-ArrayBufferView) as an expected argument to `.send()`, which are `TypedArray`s. The MDN document should probably be edited and updated to include that omission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit, Updated

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#send()) is not the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#network). The MDN documentation as to `.send()` method of `WebSocket` omits the [`ArrayBufferView`](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#common-ArrayBufferView) option included at the actual specification, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1409752.

---

You can use [`.subarray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray) to create a new view to an existing `TypedArray`

> Also note that this is creating a new view on the existing buffer;
>   changes to the new object's contents will impact the original object
>   and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of that method and it alone doesn't help. How do you send the TypedArray over a WebSocket? The send method requires a buffer.

Comment: @DrewNoakes _"How do you send the TypedArray over a WebSocket?"_ Pass the `TypedArray` to `.send()` plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/qNLOByFtVh6REYfc8f4d?p=preview

Comment: @DrewNoakes Note, it is also possible to try the same code locally, without using an external service, ignoring the `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error thrown http://plnkr.co/edit/EKlkv8KhqjWqzfqO93jO?p=preview; see  http://jsfiddle.net/adamboduch/JVfkt/

Comment: Nice. That works. Great that you raised a ticket against the MDN docs. I'm actually using TypeScript and the type of the parameter on `send` is `any`, which is quite uncommon for `lib.d.ts` in my experience. I'll look into whether that can be tightened up as well.