# How to manually create multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data

We can use [`.formData()`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-formdata) of [`Body`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body) mixin to return a `FormData` representation of data at [Chromium (Chrome) 60+ and Firefox 39+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData#Browser_compatibility)

Relevant specifications:

- [7.2 The Multipart Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)
- [Returning Values from Forms:  multipart/form-data](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)

Errata

- [Clarification of Body package data algorithm with bytes, FormData and multipart/form-data MIME type #392](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/392)
- [Documenting de-facto handling of multipart/form-data form field file uploads #3040](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3040)

Related

- [Multipart HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067312/multipart-http-response)
- [How to upload files in Web Workers when FormData is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13870853/)

How to manually create `multipart/form-data` using JavaScript at client and at server to serve the `multipart/form-data` as a response?

Comment: The `Body.formData()` method is meant to be used by ServiceWorkers which would intercept user's request before it's been sent to the server. To create a FormData manually, you can use the FormData Constructor.

Comment: @Kaiido How did you draw the conclusion that `Body.formData()` is meant to be used for a specific purpose only? Am trying to build the `multipart/form-data` string by hand, from scratch, without using `FormData()`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData

Comment: @Kaiido Your source is the MDN document only?

Comment: And the reading of what this method does. Servers usually don't send FormData requests to browsers, but maybe you've got a case?

Comment: @Kaiido MDN can be edited by users of MDN. That is not a binding document as to the intended usage of `Body.formData()` https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-body-formdata

Comment: @Kaiido We can get the raw `multipart/form-data` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111982/get-http-body-of-form-in-javascript/, though how to create the data by hand?

Comment: Regarding you previous comment, I know MDN is driven by users, but this note was added by an MDN's official and don't bind anything, it just points out what motivated the creation of this method, it doesn't say you can **only** use it from SeviceWorkers. If you really want to create such data yourself, https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#multipart/form-data-encoding-algorithm and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7578 But I don't see why send such data from a server since it is meant to return *a set of values as
   the result of a user filling out a form*.

Comment: @Kaiido The specification does not state that is the reason for `.formData()` usage. A server is not involved in the procedure

Comment: @Kaiido MDN is a valuable resource, though an occasional error or omission could occur https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072936/is-it-possible-to-display-an-html-document-or-html-fragment-at-css-content, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718355/sending-a-sub-segment-of-an-arraybuffer-over-a-websocket-without-copying

Comment: Yes "I know MDN is driven by users" and do contains errors => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter$history https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode$history

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating HTTP multipart body for file upload in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455475/generating-http-multipart-body-for-file-upload-in-javascript)

Comment: @Aleksi I'll have to test the code in the answers.

Answer (score 17):

You can create `multipart/form-data` manually with XMLHttpRequest like this example.

```
function multiPost(method, url, formHash){
    var boundary = "nVenJ7H4puv"
    var body = ""
    for(var key in formHash){
        body += "--" + boundary
             + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=" + formHash[key].name
             + "\r\nContent-type: " + formHash[key].type
             + "\r\n\r\n" + formHash[key].value + "\r\n"
    }
    body += "--" + boundary + "--\r\n"

    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.open(method, url)
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary)
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", body.length)
    xml.send(body)
}
```

Comment: Yes it would be better, if it is file type.

Comment: The code at Answer does not handle `<input type="file" name="abc">` `<input type="file" name="abc" multiple>`, correct?

Comment: You can handle file similar way.
If your server can accept the base64, you can send file in base64 format with adding body `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`. It would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529159/javascript-isnt-uploading-binary-data

Comment: The code at your Answer does not handle `<input type="file">` element

Comment: We need a working example with an input of type file. Also, what is "formHash" in your code ?

Comment: @trogne im ahving same problem as you did you solve it?

Comment: I struggled with this! I was sending a FormData object to server in the body of a post. I found that the problem was with my Content-type header for that post! I just removed the Content-type header, then the browser created the correct multipart form data header for me, and voila! I got the idea from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280438/fetch-missing-boundary-in-multipart-form-data-post

Answer (score 3):

You can write you own FormData polyfill, or just google it "FormData polyfill"))) And also you can use normal FormData at browsers Chrome, FireFox, Opera, Safari, IE(10+), Edge.
FormData polyfill is only useful for old IE, and for workers, but for workers you better should use this - https://gist.github.com/Rob--W/8b5adedd84c0d36aba64

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Form-Data)

[standart formdata not of body](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData)

**What you need to do? You want send formdata or recieve it at js?**

You can try to use my polyfill, but I have not tested it.

sample:

```
var data = new RawFormData();
data.append("key","value")
data.append("key", new Blob("test"), "my file.txt");
data.getOutputDeferred().then(function(formData){
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + data.getBoundry());
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", formData.length);
    xml.open(method, url);
    xml.send(formData);
});
```

code:

```
/**
* @constructor
*/
RawFormData = function () {
    this._promises = [];
    this._boundry = this.makeBoundary();
};

/**
* @return {string}
*/
RawFormData.prototype.getBoundary = function () {
    return this._boundry;
}

/**
* @return {string}
*/
RawFormData.prototype.makeBoundary = function () {
    return 'MyBoundary' + window.btoa(Math.random().toString()).substr(0, 12);
};

/**
* @param {string} name
* @param {string|number|File|Blob|boolean|null|undefined} val
* @param {string=} filename
*/
RawFormData.prototype.append = function (name, val, filename) {
    var prom = null;

    if(val instanceof File || val instanceof Blob){
        prom = this.readAsBinaryString(val).then(function(base64){
            var contentType = val.type || 'application/octet-stream';
            var result = '--' + this._boundry + '\r\n' +
                'Content-Disposition: form-data; ' +
                'name="' + name + '"; filename="' + this.encode_utf8(filename || "blob") + '"\r\n' +
                'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n\r\n' +
                base64 + '\r\n';
            return result;
        }.bind(this))
    }else{
        prom = new Promise(function(resolve){
            return '--' + this._boundry + '\r\n' +
                'Content-Disposition: form-data; ' +
                'name="' + this.encode_utf8(name) + '"\r\n\r\n' +
                this.encode_utf8(val) + '\r\n'
        }.bind(this));
    }

    this._promises.push(prom);

    return prom;
};
/**
* @return {File|Blob} blob
* @return {Promise<string>}
*/
RawFormData.prototype.readAsBinaryString = function (blob) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            var binStringCallback = function (e) {
                resolve(e.target.result);
            };

            var arrBufferCallback = function (e) {
                var binary = "";
                var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                var length = bytes.byteLength;
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                }
                resolve(binary);
            };

            reader.onerror = reader.onabort = function () {
                resolve(null);
            };

            if (typeof reader.readAsBinaryString != "undefined") {
                reader.onload = binStringCallback;
                reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
            } else {
                reader.onload = arrBufferCallback;
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
            }
        });
};

RawFormData.prototype.encode_utf8 = function( s ){
   return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
}

RawFormData.prototype.getOutputDeferred = function () {
    return Promise.all(this._promises).then(function (rows) {
        var output = '--' + this._boundry + '\r\n';
        rows.forEach(function(row) {
            output += row;
        });
        output += '--' + this._boundry + '\r\n';
        return output;
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: We are looking for a simple and clear answer on how to send a file without using the FormData api. That is, mimic the FormData api work. That is, creating the object that FormData api creates.

Comment: @trogne you can send a file as base64 and attach it to request like a string. In modern browsers, you can use WebSocket and fetch API

Comment: I know I can send as base64, but that's not what I want. I want to mimic FormData and not changing the server side code.